# Unequal distribution of space between two column

Tags: html, css, sass

Here is the code for my grid consisting of four square grids. However, the difference between the two columns is unequal. How can I ensure equal spacing?

```
.industriesFeatureInner {
    h2 {
        margin-top: 6rem;
        font-size: 2rem;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
    }

    .industriesFeatureList {
        flex-direction: row;
        gap: 2rem;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;

        .industriesFeatureListRow {
            flex-direction: column;
            gap: 2rem;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output of the above styling
[image for ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfBL0.png)

Comment: Can u plz share a codepen or sandbox of the working code

Answer (score 1):

Set `width` of `grid` item like

```
Width:calc((100% / 2 )- 2rem);
```

`Width 100% / 2 = 50% - 2rem = real width`

`Edit`

```css
.view{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   gap: 0.8rem; 
   justify-content: center;
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
.item{
   height:4rem;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   background:#000000;
   width: calc((100% / 2) - 0.8rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="view">
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
</div>
```